# High cpu load during animation

Tags: android, animation, image-rotation

During the animation the cpu load is very high (up to 75%)

**Is there a method to optimize the code to get lower cpu load?**

My code:

ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);

```
    animSet = new AnimationSet(true);

    animSet.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animSet.setFillAfter(true);
    animSet.setFillEnabled(true);

    final RotateAnimation animRotate = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    animRotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    animRotate.setDuration(rotor_duration());
    animRotate.setFillAfter(true);
    animSet.addAnimation(animRotate);

    myImageView.startAnimation(animSet);
```

Comment: I have same problem , did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a method to set delay between rotations ? By setting a delay and setting a bigger value for the angle (to keep rotation speed constant) should help.